# display the number of product with static block in categories?

Tags: magento-1.7, category

I am using magento 1.7. I create a category "A" and in it i create others categories. 
I created a static block and affect to the category "A". I wish to display the categories name and his count in all categories using static block. Can i do that with static block or with other solution ?

Answer (score 2):

You sure can - first, create a custom block:

```
YourCompany_YourModule_Block_Category extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
{
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $category = Mage::registry('current_category');
        $name = $category->getName();
        $numProducts = $category->getCollection()->getSize();

        $html = parent::_toHtml();
        return $html .= "$name, number of products: $numProducts";

    }
}
```

Then you add it to your static block:

```
{{block type='yourblock/category' name='your.custom.name'}}
```

If all goes well, you should see at the top of your category something like "Televisions, number of products: 42".

Best of luck!

Comment: I must create a new module ?